# ShellExecuteEx 7z Delphi

Tags: delphi, shellexecuteex

So I'm trying to do a archive using delphi and ShellExecuteEx my code is :

```
 Result := False;
  DecodeDate(now,y,m,d);
  NumeFisier := dir+'\Export_'+IntToStr(y)+'.'+IntToStr(m)+'.'+IntToStr(d)+'.zip';
  FillChar(exInfo, SizeOf(exInfo), 0);
  with exInfo do
   begin
    cbSize := SizeOf(exInfo);
    fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS or SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT;
    Wnd := GetActiveWindow();
    exInfo.lpVerb := nil;
    exInfo.lpFile  := PAnsiChar('C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe');
   exInfo.lpParameters := PAnsiChar('C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe ' +'a ' + NumeFisier + ' ' + dir);
    nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
   end;
   if ShellExecuteEx(@exInfo) then
    Ph := exInfo.hProcess
    else
     begin
     ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
     Result := true;
     exit;
    end;
   while WaitForSingleObject(exInfo.hProcess, 50) <> WAIT_OBJECT_0 do
     Application.ProcessMessages;
   CloseHandle(Ph);

  Result := true;
```

For some reason this only opens the Command Prompt and doesn't execute the archiving. How can I make it execute the 7z.exe file.

I tried with ShellExecute and it works great, but I have to check then the process is finished, so I'm stuck with ShellExecuteEx

Comment: Don't call cmd.exe but 7z.exe directly.

Comment: Thank you! It works, i though that I have to call first the cmd in order to execute the 7z.exe :). Your answer saved me a lot of time. Post it as an answer so I can accept it, please.

Comment: Since a question needs an answer, feel free to answer your own question.

Comment: Don't use ShellExecute. Use CreateProcess.

Comment: Don't use `SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to involve `cmd.exe`. That's the command interpreter. You want to execute a different executable so do that directly.

You don't want to use `ShellExecuteEx` since that has far more generality than you need. All that `ShellExecuteEx` is doing here is calling `CreateProcess`. You should do that directly and avoid the middle man. What's more, calling `CreateProcess` allows you to hide the console window easily. Pass `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` to achieve that.

Finally, there are better ways to wait than your code. Using `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` allows you to avoid polling. And putting this code into a thread would allow you to avoid calls to `Application.ProcessMessages`.

```
procedure WaitUntilSignaled(Handle: THandle; ProcessMessages: Boolean);
var
  retval: DWORD;
begin
  if ProcessMessages then begin
    Application.ProcessMessages;//in case there are messages already in the queue
    while True do begin
      retval := MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, Handle, False, INFINITE, QS_ALLEVENTS);
      case retval of
      WAIT_OBJECT_0,WAIT_ABANDONED_0:
        break;
      WAIT_OBJECT_0+1:
        Application.ProcessMessages;
      WAIT_FAILED:
        RaiseLastOSError;
      end;
    end;
  end else begin
    Win32Check(WaitForSingleObject(Handle, INFINITE)<>WAIT_FAILED);
  end;
end;

procedure ExecuteProcess(
  const ExecutablePath: string;
  const Arguments: string;
  const CurrentDirectory: string;
  const Wait: Boolean;
  const CreationFlags: DWORD
);
var
  si: TStartupInfo;
  pi: TProcessInformation;
  MyCurrentDirectory: PChar;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@si, SizeOf(si));
  si.cb := SizeOf(si);

  if CurrentDirectory <> '' then begin
    MyCurrentDirectory := PChar(CurrentDirectory);
  end else begin
    MyCurrentDirectory := nil;
  end;

  Win32Check(CreateProcess(
    nil,
    PChar('"' + ExecutablePath + '" ' + Arguments),
    nil,
    nil,
    False,
    CreationFlags,
    nil,
    MyCurrentDirectory,
    si,
    pi
  ));
  try
    if Wait then begin
      WaitUntilSignaled(pi.hProcess, True);
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I've tried :   NumeFisier := ChangeFileExt('test.Bak', '.7z');
  if FileExists ( NumeFisier ) then DeleteFile(NumeFisier);
   ExecuteProcess('"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7za.exe" ' , ' a ' + NumeFisier + ' ' + 'D:\TestBK\*.bak' ,'',True,0); and I get the error "Invalid handler"

Comment: That's a little hard to understand. You use the code in the answer verbatim I presume?

Comment: The error is in "WaitUntilSignaled" at RaiseLastOSError;

Comment: You aren't using the code in my answer. If you were then you'd get invalid parameter in the call to `CreateProcess`. The problem is that you are double quoting the file name. Should be: `ExecuteProcess('C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7za.exe', 'a ' + NumeFisier + ' ' + 'D:\TestBK*.bak', '', True, 0)`

Comment: Thank you, I've used "" as in Command Promt I've got error because of the space between Program and Files

Comment: If you would use the code in my answer then you would not have that problem. The code in my answer already adds quotes inside `ExecuteProcess`.

Comment: I've used that code, but didn't see the Quotes, so that's why I've got the error :).

Comment: as a last question if in WaitUntilSignaled I change the  Application.ProcessMessages; with  ServiceThread.ProcessRequests; will it work for a service?

Comment: Perhaps. Not really my area of expertise. I say that a better approach would be to run the code in a thread and get it to signal upon completion.